# understand the tab bar interface in UITabBarController

Tags: ios, interface, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am currently studying `UITabBarController` in Apple doc but I haven't clear what is the **tab bar interface**. Could you explain me this concept? Thank you in advence.

Comment: that so mean can't u see i m a newbie trying to learn why u voted to -1 .....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Apple doc:

> This tab bar interface displays tabs at the bottom of the window for
> selecting between the different modes and for displaying the views for
> that mode.
>
> The view for a tab bar controller is just a container for a tab bar
> view and the view containing your custom content.

The tab bar interface is composed by two different parts at glance: a view and the tab bar. The latter is a sort of navigation bar (that is collocated at the bottom of the window) where it's possible to find different tabs. The tab bar interface has a radio-style selection interface: it means that only one tab can be selected each time. In [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) the tab bar is the bar where you can find tabs named "World Clock", "Alarm", etc. The former instead is the view attached with the `UITabBarController` (`UITabBarController` is a `UIViewController`).

The behaviour of the `UITabBarController` is quite straight. This controller can contains `UIViewController` elements. When you create a new `UITabBarController` and add to it a `UIViewController`, the view of that `UIViewController` is attached the view of the `UITabBarController`.

You can change the current visible content (the bar remains visible) selecting a specific tab in the bar. When you do this, the `UITabBarController` retrieves the `UIViewController`associated with that tab and presents its view as the current visible content in your `UITabBarController`.

Hope it helps.